# Como escapar virgulas de valores monetários em um array php?

Tags: php

Como escapar virgulas de valores monetários em um array php? tenho o array abaixo com 12 posições porém a virgula que separa os decimais está me dando problemas, o php entende que é uma nova posição do array e separa o valor, como contornar isso ?

```
data: [ 0,00,
        0,00,
        0,00,
        0,00,
        0,00,
        0,00,
        0,00,
        0,00,
        2.468,00,
        2.093,00,
        600,00,
        0,00
]
```

Comment: Não tem como montar esse array com os valores entre aspas?

Comment: Como está sendo montado esse `array`?

Comment: Deixa os valores como string

Comment: Nem deveria ter vírgula, pra começo de conversa. Decimal em PHP é separado por ponto (e não tem aspas). melhor mesmo seria informar com inteiros, já que é monetário (informar em centavos) e formatar apenas na exibição. Agora, se está recebendo estes dados, converta na entrada (mas aí já é um problema completamente diferente do que foi exposto na pergunta)

Answer (score -1):

Você pode usar algo como:

```
$data = [
    '0,00',
    '0,00',
    '0,00',
    '0,00',
    '0,00',
    '0,00',
    '0,00',
    '0,00',
    '2.468,00',
    '2.093,00',
    '600,00',
    '0,00'
 ];

$valores = array_map(function($valor){
   return str_replace(",",".",str_replace(".","",$valor))
},$data);
```